# my fullcalendar page works fine with Chrome,But not in IE6 and Firefox

Tags: fullcalendar

I have made a PHP script with fullcalendar， It works fine with Chrome,But not in IE6 and Firefox, actually I just follow the documents and demo, I'm puzzled what's wrong ?

The page's URL is http://jiangzuokong.com/cal.php

script like follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },

            editable: false,
            events: [
                        {
            title  : '资本主义作为一种历史现象',
            start  : '2011-3-7',
            url  : 'http://jiangzuokong.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=80&from=portal'
                },

            title  : '【在文学馆听讲座】关仁山：乡村社会转型中的文学[北京]',
            start  : '2011-3-13',
            url  : 'http://jiangzuokong.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=104&from=portal'
                },      {
            title  : 'Survival Chinese：Ordering Food[北京]',
            start  : '2011-3-13',
            url  : 'http://jiangzuokong.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=105&from=portal'
                },      {
            title  : '',
            start  : '',
            url  : ''
                }           ]
        });

    });

</script> 
<style type='text/css'> 

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style> 
</head>
```